# Javascript - Calling a child method from inside a prototype method

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

Is it possible to call a regular method from a prototype method if it's been overridden?  Note that in the given example the first eat() method is called from the body of the Animal function - it is the requirement.

```
Animal = function(){
    this.eat();
};

Animal.prototype.eat = function() {
    console.log("All animals eat");
};

Bear = function(){
    Animal.call(this);
    this.goToSleep = function(){
        console.log("Bears go to sleep after they eat");
    }
};

Bear.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);

Bear.prototype.eat = function() {
    console.log("Bears eat honey");
    this.goToSleep(); //returns 'undefined is not a function'
    //How do I invoke this.goToSleep() ?
};

var winnie = new Bear();
```

Comment: Why not define it as `Bear.prototype.goToSleep`?

Comment: You shouldn't mix the functional pattern with the prototype pattern. Either define all methods on the prototype or define them all on every instance. (The prototype pattern is preferable because it avoids duplication.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your bear doesn't have a `goToSleep` method when `eat` first gets invoked.

When you invoke `Animal.call(this)` in your `Bear` constructor it then calls `eat` - which is found on `Bear.prototype` and invoked.  Then `eat` tries to invoke `goToSleep` but `goToSleep` is an instance method that you haven't added yet (remember, we are still on `Animal.call` we haven't reached `this.goToSleep = function()` yet).

Unless you have a good reason to, `goToSleep` should be a prototype method as well, just like `eat`:

```
Bear.prototype.goToSleep = function(){
  console.log("Bears go to sleep after they eat");
};
```

This will *just work* as you want it to.

Alternatively, if `goToSleep` *has* to be an instance method (because it needs access to some private state you create in your constructor), then simply switch the order of your `Animal.call` and `this.goToSleep` lines:

```
this.goToSleep = function() // etc.
Animal.call(this);
```

Comment: Sean, thank you for the detailed and insightful answer. You made my day!  

The problem was that the real project equivalent of goToSleep() needs to access methods and properties of the base class function (i.e. Animal), therefore it can't be a prototype method. 

Switching the lines did the magic!

Comment: In those cases what I normally do is expose the super prototype on object via the `SubConstructor.prototype.$super = SuperConstructor.prototype` method.  Then I can just do `this.$super.someMethod.call(this, arg1, arg2, argN)`.